# How Do I Output The Build Number By Branch In Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I publish to SNAPSHOTS, my artifacts are named based on the branch name and the number of times the branch has been built.
In Bamboo this is `${bamboo.planRepository.branchName}_${bamboo.buildNumber}`.
e.g. if my branch name is `MyGreatFeature` and the pipeline for that branch has been run 4 times then artifact name would be `MyGreatFeature_4`

How do I get this in Azure DevOps?
Remember, this is an incrementing value *per branch*.

If there is no built in variable like in Bamboo, can it be done by the REST API?
e.g. query for a list of runs by branch then parse the output by counting the number of runs in the response

Comment: What do you need is to get the build number during a build execution in Az DevOps?

Comment: I need to get the build number per branch as I am migrating from Bamboo and the rest of the deploy relies on it. It has to be the build number per branch not the overall build number.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "build number per branch". Every build has a unique ID regardless of the branch it's from. Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Example is already in the question. I changed my phrasing in the comment to be more confusing! By "build number per branch" I mean the number of times that branch has been run.

Comment: You'd be looking for a runtime expression using the `counter` function, something like `$(Build.SourceBranchName)_$[ counter(variables['Build.SourceBranchName', 0]) ]`. Refer to the documentation for more details.

Comment: See "[predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)" and "[Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)" and, in Expressions, "[counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter)"

Comment: Lots of comments and no answers. I have been reading the docs and not getting anywhere which is why I asked the question. Is it as simple as Rev:r? Is that per branch? The example expression doesn't return a value when I echo it as a variable. The docs show lower case. Does it matter? Are we using the built in name here? Why isn't it with a $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the `counter` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions) with a seed of the current branch name to create a unique counter per branch name.

```
trigger: none
name: $(Build.SourceBranchName)_$(branchCounter)
variables: 
  branchCounter: $[counter(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 0)]
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

Note that the seed is the branch name, so if you ever re-use a branch name, the counter will *not* reset to zero.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation at "[Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)". You want something like the following:

```yaml
name: $(SourceBranchName)_$(Rev:r)

steps:
  - script: echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

This is customizing the `Build.BuildNumber` to be the branch name, and a counter. The `$(Rev:r)` special variable increments. It is a counter and counters are scoped to the build definition.

Also see "[Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)" and "[Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)".

Comment: Yes, `SourceBranchName` is not a built-in variable. It is a special token recognized for defining a `BuildNumber`. `$(Rev:r)` is a counter and is unique per unique string that it is used in. If the branch name is used in the string then the counter is unique per branch. `main_$(Rev:r)` and `MyGreatFeature_$(Rev:r)` are two different counters. Under the hood `$(Rev:r)` is a counter and is scoped to the build definition.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of that behavior of `$(Rev:r)`. Consider my criticism retracted!